# How to return value through a pointer in Rust

Tags: rust, ownership

I'm having trouble understanding how to create a string that I can "return" to the caller, without violating lifetimes.

I have a simple function of type

```
pub extern fn get_string(file: &mut &mut String) -> i32
```

It should create a string (allocate it in the right way) and pass it back to the caller through `file`. I know that this is a very "C" thing to do and Rust can return strings, but that's what I need to do here.

I need some assistance with the ownership. I tried:

```
pub extern fn get_string(file: &mut &mut String) -> i32 {
    let my_str:String = "String passed in Rust.\n".to_owned();
    local_file = &mut &mut my_str_ptr;
    
    return 0;
}
```

But obviously `my_str` is local and will not survive the end of the function. How do I transfer the ownership correctly?

In the solution, I can allocate the string as I see fit (Hopefully using rust's `String`) but then I really need to pass the reference through the pointer.

Comment: `&mut &mut String` in Rust implies that you can do `**file = my_str;`, but somehow I feel like that’s not the whole story. Please include relevant context (e.g. an FFI interface you have to conform to) in your question, and try not to suffer from [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It sounds like what you want is for the caller to allocate some heap memory, pass you a pointer to it, and you write the string to the memory that pointer points at. Is that correct? Frankly if that's not correct I don't understand this at all.

Comment: As previous comments noticed, the function's signature somewhat suggests that you are asking the wrong question. A `&mut &mut String` in an `extern fn` is a rather strange type to have. Remember that `String` is more than just a "good old c-like string". In case this is actually what you have, you can use `std::mem::replace` to put a new (owned) String into what the nested (?!) references point to: `drop(std::mem::replace(*file, "Foo".to_owned()));`

Comment: Maybe the references are nested because the idea is to allocate a String on the heap, then change the passed-in pointer to now point to the new address. Very C-ish. :D

Comment: @user2722968 No need to use `std::mem::replace()` if you don't use the old value, just use a simple assignment.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman , I brainfarted here

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this, but I'm not certain about the intention of such an assignment to `&mut &mut String`.

If `file` is `&mut &mut s` in `main()`, then `*file` is `&mut s` (i.e. `r`) and `**file` is `s`.

```rust
pub fn get_string(file: &mut &mut String) -> i32 {
    let my_str: String = "String passed in Rust.\n".to_owned();
    **file = my_str;
    return 0;
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = "original".to_owned();
    let mut r = &mut s;
    let i = get_string(&mut r);
    println!("i={:?} s={:?}", i, s);
}
/*
i=0 s="String passed in Rust.\n"
*/
```